# Compare All Adjacent Elements of Array

Tags: python, algorithm, datetime

I have a log file that includes different Mac address in different lines.

I can extract the lines that includes given Mac address and then I can trim the line to get only timestamp(such as 15:48:55) then I add this timestamps to an array.

What I want is;

How can I compare all adjacent elements of array if their timestamp subtraction is bigger than 2 seconds?

Log file example:

```
info: 02-03-2018, 15:48:55.730, 192.168.1.4, 33826, 5C-CF-7F-29-AB-73, 22496
info: 02-03-2018, 15:48:55.894, 192.168.1.6, 17948, A0-20-A6-0A-F2-AB, 22475
info: 02-03-2018, 15:48:56.031, 192.168.1.3, 32538, A0-20-A6-0A-2F-D5, 22510
info: 02-03-2018, 15:48:56.742, 192.168.1.7, 40596, 60-01-94-16-05-96, 22490
info: 02-03-2018, 15:48:57.475, 192.168.1.5, 30646, 5C-CF-7F-DA-5B-77, 22668
info: 02-03-2018, 15:48:57.780, 192.168.1.4, 39592, 5C-CF-7F-29-AB-73, 22497
info: 02-03-2018, 15:48:57.922, 192.168.1.6, 21467, A0-20-A6-0A-F2-AB, 22476
info: 02-03-2018, 15:48:58.055, 192.168.1.3, 13001, A0-20-A6-0A-2F-D5, 22511
info: 02-03-2018, 15:48:58.760, 192.168.1.7, 31030, 60-01-94-16-05-96, 22491
info: 02-03-2018, 15:48:59.487, 192.168.1.5, 46505, 5C-CF-7F-DA-5B-77, 22669
```

What I got so far:

```
from datetime import datetime
import os
import re

# Regex used to match relevant loglines (in this case, a specific MAC address)
line_regex = re.compile(r'A0-20-A6-0A-F2-AB')

with open("info.log", "r") as in_file:

    # Loop over each log line
    for line in in_file:

        # If log line matches our regex
        if (line_regex.search(line)):

            #Extract the timestamp as 15:48:55
            asd = line[18:26]

            #Convert to datetime_object
            datetime_object = datetime.strptime(asd, '%H:%M:%S')

            #Trim begining of the datetime object
            dsa = datetime_object.strftime ('%H:%M:%S')

            #Add to an array as a timestamp
            for j in range(1):
                    array1=[]
                    for i in range(1):
                        array1.append(dsa)
                        print array1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't really need extra modules for this, you just need to use the datetime object, not a string.

```
from datetime import datetime
import os
import re

line_regex = re.compile(r'A0-20-A6-0A-F2-AB')

prev_dsa = None
with open("info.log", "r") as in_file:
    for line in in_file:
        if (line_regex.search(line)):
            asd = line[6:26]
            dsa = datetime.strptime(asd, '%m-%d-%Y, %H:%M:%S')
            if (prev_dsa != None):
                if abs((dsa - prev_dsa).seconds) >= 2:
                    print dsa
            prev_dsa = dsa
```

Comment: It returns nothing. Should I assign previous day to `prev_dsa` ? How can I make this?

Comment: Yes, sorry, a line was not copied and pasted from my editor.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pandas` for this. Note: this can easily be adapted to take date into account, but as it stands it only takes into account the time component.

```
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv', header=None, delimiter=', ')
df['Diff'] = pd.to_datetime(df[1], format='%H:%M:%S.%f').diff().dt.microseconds / 10**6

# greater than half a second differences
res = df[df['Diff'] > 0.5]

#                   0             1            2      3                  4  \
# 3  info: 02-03-2018  15:48:56.742  192.168.1.7  40596  60-01-94-16-05-96   
# 4  info: 02-03-2018  15:48:57.475  192.168.1.5  30646  5C-CF-7F-DA-5B-77   
# 8  info: 02-03-2018  15:48:58.760  192.168.1.7  31030  60-01-94-16-05-96   
# 9  info: 02-03-2018  15:48:59.487  192.168.1.5  46505  5C-CF-7F-DA-5B-77   

#        5   Diff  
# 3  22490  0.711  
# 4  22668  0.733  
# 8  22491  0.705  
# 9  22669  0.727
```

Comment: This will probably fail around midnight, if you don't take into accound day, month and year

Comment: @ChatterOne, agreed. I added a disclaimer. It's easy enough to incorporate date too, if required, in `pd.to_datetime`.

Comment: Before finding the difference, I need to sort according to given Mac address. Is it possible with `pandas`?